# What is JSESSIONID cookie when connecting to Spotfire server?

Tags: django, cookies, embed, spotfire, samesite

I am embedding a Spotfire visualization into my Django webpage.
I am using the following JS API: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/spotfire-tipstricks-embed-spotfire-visualizations-webpages

The API works well except that it gives me a cookie error like the following:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The JSESSIONID is a session cookie. To use cookies across domains like this you need to set `SameSite=None` on these cookies. Instructions on how to do this can be found in the [TIBCO Spotfire Server and Environment - Installation and Administration](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/11.6.3/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/server/topics/samesite_cookie_attribute.html) manual. Note that your server must be using HTTPS for this to work.